# Attribute doesn't exist error when executing ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to execute an existing ansible playbook and I get this error:

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! 'unicode object' has no attribute 'regexp'"}
```

When executing this part of the ansible playbook:

```
- name: "Add access to pg_hba.conf for DB users"
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  lineinfile: dest="{{ PATH_PG_HBA }}" regexp="{{ item.regexp }}" line="{{ item.line }}" state=present create=yes
  with_items: "{{ DATABASE_ACL }}"
  notify: restart postgresql
```

Obviously the regexp doesnt exist in the object. But as my experience in ansible is limited, I wonder if this is a generic error related to the lineinfile parameter or something specific of this ansible yaml file.

The {{ DATABASE_ACL }} variable is declared in group_vars folder as:

```
DATABASE_ACL:
 - "local {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} md5"
 - "host {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} 127.0.0.1/32 md5"
 - "host {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} 10.0.2.2/32 md5"
```

In the same folder is declared the DB_NAME and DB_USER (strings).

Comment: Please include your `DATABASE_ACL` variable in question, also where did you declared it? Inside playbook, group_vars, extra vars, inventory?

Comment: @Andrew I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATABASE_ACL` from your group vars is a list of strings, and `item` in loop is a unicode string. Obviously, as you said, this error tells you exactly this - unicode string doesn't have attribute regexp. This exact error can be reproduced in ipython, like:

```
In [1]: a = unicode("some string")

In [2]: a.regexp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-26893273be72> in <module>()
----> 1 a.regexp

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'regexp'
```

If you want to use your current task, you have to change data structure of `DATABASE_ACL` to a list of dicts in a yaml, for example like

```
DATABASE_ACL:
 - line: "local {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} md5"
   regexp: "local"
 - line: "host {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} 127.0.0.1/32 md5"
   regexp: "host .* 127"
 - line: "host {{ DB_NAME }} {{ DB_USER }} 10.0.2.2/32 md5"
   regexp: "host .* 10.0.2.2"
```

The resulting `item` will be dict, structured as `{line: "your line", regexp: "your regexp"}`, which will work correctly in your case.